# What does ppm/K correspond to?

Tags: resistance, temperature

I have a precision resistor 10 ohm and 5ppm/K. Does it mean that on delta 1K it will jump up/down 5 ppm of 1 ohm or 5ppm of resistor value - 10 ohms?

I think that it corresponds to resistor value. But Im not sure 100%.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

5ppm/K means that the resistance will change by 5 parts per million per 1 [Kelvin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kelvin) change in temperature.

The datasheet for your resistor should give the baseline temperature, but it's probably 20C (roughly 293K).  So, if the temperature of your resistor is actually 300K (27C) then it's resistance will be 10 * (1 + (7 * 0.000005)) = 10.00035R.

Comment: Or it might be going below 10R

Comment: @Andyaka True but as a general rule higher temperature => higher resistance.  There are exceptions of course.

Comment: Not true - most manufacturers specify (say) 5ppm/K but when you read the data sheets they actually mean +/-5ppm/K.

Comment: @Andyaka You may be right about datasheets - a Bourns SMD resistor datasheet I have to hand agrees with your point - but I'm going to go with physics and repeat that resistors will _generally_ have a positive temperature co-efficient.

Comment: I believe resistors are made from material that have both positive and negative temperature coefficients - which ever one has most dominance will win.

Comment: You're both right ... resistors in general will have PTC, but resistors aiming at precision will attempt to cancel that out : the resultant coefficient can be either positive or negative and may vary from batch to batch.

Comment: @MuhammedM, can you please explain your edit to the question? Why do you think that a 7 K change in temperature will result in a change of 300 times the temperature coefficient?

Comment: @MuhammedM, I have rolled back your edit which suggested that you think that the resistor's value is specified at 0 K and so if operated at 300 K that it requires 300 x tempco correction. This is incorrect. The answer was correct. Please read it again.

Answer (score 1):

It just depends on what material it is, some materials have a positive Temperature Coefficient of Resistance and some have a negative TCR, lots of common materials and metals have a positive TCR, some though, like silicon have a negative TCR which is what leads to thermal runaway situations in silicon integrated circuits and stuff like that. As the silicon heats up, it's resistance goes down, so it draws more amps, and heats up more and draws more amps, etc. till it blows up. Common sense tells you more heat equals more resistance, and frequently this is true, but there are a surprising number of materials in which the opposite is true. Most thermistors for measuring temperature are Negative Temperature Coefficient thermistors, meaning their resistance drops with an increase in temperature, most thermistors for circuit protection are Positive Temperature Coefficient resistors, and act sort of like self-resetting fuses.

Comment: Welcome to EE stack exchange! It seems you have answered a question which is more than 4 years old and already has an accepted answer. I recommend you build your reputation by answering newer questions which do not already have an accepted answer. Also, after reading through your answer, I am not sure it actually does address the main question of the original poster. Answers are more likely to receive upvotes if they do answer the original question.